# "Google Chrome is using your microphone" doesn't disappear after disconnecting AudioNode from Web Audio

Tags: google-chrome, web-audio-api, getusermedia

I'm currently calling the disconnect() function on my AudioNode instances in Web Audio after a user evokes a Stop Recording function, but the "Google Chrome is using your microphone" status continues to persist on the top menu. What specifically does Chrome look for in determining whether or not the mic is still active?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep a reference to the "stream" object you were handed in the success callback to getUserMedia(), and call

```
stream.stop();
```

on it.  That will get rid of the indicator.